# Is it possible to change class object instance locally in python?

Tags: python, class

I am a beginner in python. I have two files.

**test.py**

```
    class UrPiece:
        def __init__(self, color, symbol):
            self.color = color
            self.position = None
            self.complete = False
            self.symbol = symbol
    
        def can_move(self, num_moves):
            pass
    
    
    
    class BoardSquare:
        def __init__(self, x, y, entrance=False, _exit=False, rosette=False, forbidden=False):
            self.piece = None
            self.position = (x, y)
            self.next_white = None
            self.next_black = None
            self.exit = _exit
            self.entrance = entrance
            self.rosette = rosette
            self.forbidden = forbidden
    
        def load_from_json(self, json_string):
            import json
            loaded_position = json.loads(json_string)
            self.piece = None
            self.position = loaded_position['position']
            self.next_white = loaded_position['next_white']
            self.next_black = loaded_position['next_black']
            self.exit = loaded_position['exit']
            self.entrance = loaded_position['entrance']
            self.rosette = loaded_position['rosette']
            self.forbidden = loaded_position['forbidden']
    
        def jsonify(self):
            next_white = self.next_white.position if self.next_white else None
            next_black = self.next_black.position if self.next_black else None
            return {'position': self.position, 'next_white': next_white, 'next_black': next_black, 'exit': self.exit, 'entrance': self.entrance, 'rosette': self.rosette, 'forbidden': self.forbidden}
```

**test2.py**

```
from test import UrPiece, BoardSquare

from sys import argv
from random import choice


WHITE = 'White'
BLACK = 'Black'


class RoyalGameOfUr:
    STARTING_PIECES = 7

    def __init__(self, board_file_name):
        self.board = None
        self.load_board(board_file_name)

    def load_board(self, board_file_name):

        import json
        try:
            with open(board_file_name) as board_file:
                board_json = json.loads(board_file.read())
                self.num_pieces = self.STARTING_PIECES
                self.board = []
                for x, row in enumerate(board_json):
                    self.board.append([])
                    for y, square in enumerate(row):
                        self.board[x].append(BoardSquare(x, y, entrance=square['entrance'], _exit=square['exit'], rosette=square['rosette'], forbidden=square['forbidden']))

                for i in range(len(self.board)):
                    for j in range(len(self.board[i])):
                        if board_json[i][j]['next_white']:
                            x, y = board_json[i][j]['next_white']
                            self.board[i][j].next_white = self.board[x][y]
                        if board_json[i][j]['next_black']:
                            x, y = board_json[i][j]['next_black']
                            self.board[i][j].next_black = self.board[x][y]
        except OSError:
            print('The file was unable to be opened. ')

    def draw_block(self, output, i, j, square):

        MAX_X = 8
        MAX_Y = 5
        for y in range(MAX_Y):
            for x in range(MAX_X):
                if x == 0 or y == 0 or x == MAX_X - 1 or y == MAX_Y - 1:
                    output[MAX_Y * i + y][MAX_X * j + x] = '+'
                if square.rosette and (y, x) in [(1, 1), (1, MAX_X - 2), (MAX_Y - 2, 1), (MAX_Y - 2, MAX_X - 2)]:
                    output[MAX_Y * i + y][MAX_X * j + x] = '*'
                if square.piece:
                    # print(square.piece.symbol)
                    output[MAX_Y * i + 2][MAX_X * j + 3: MAX_X * j + 5] = square.piece.symbol

    def display_board(self):
        """
        Draws the board contained in the self.board object

        """
        if self.board:
            #print(self.board[1][0].piece)
            output = [[' ' for _ in range(8 * len(self.board[i//5]))] for i in range(5 * len(self.board))]
            for i in range(len(self.board)):
                for j in range(len(self.board[i])):
                    if not self.board[i][j].forbidden:
                        self.draw_block(output, i, j, self.board[i][j])

            print('\n'.join(''.join(output[i]) for i in range(5 * len(self.board))))

    def roll_d4_dice(self, n=4):

        dots = 0
        for _ in range(n):
            dots += choice([0, 1])
        return dots


    def play_game(self):

        self.display_board()




if __name__ == '__main__':
   # file_name = input('What is the file name of the board json? ') if len(argv) < 2 else argv[1]
    file_name = 'two_lines.ur'
    rgu = RoyalGameOfUr(file_name)
    rgu.play_game()
```

here self.display_board() prints the board. It doesn't take any argumants. I need to display a UrPiece object on the board.

I tried creating an instance of BoardSqure class on play game funcion, but it doesn't work.
I'm a total beginner at python. I would be really grateful if anyone can explain what to do or point at any resources I could read. Thank you.

**output:**

```
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
```

**expected output:**

```
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+   W  +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
++++++++        ++++++++
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
+      +        +      +
++++++++        ++++++++
```

**two_lines.ur**

```
[[{"position": [0, 0], "next_white": [1, 0], "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "White", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [0, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [0, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": [1, 2], "exit": "", "entrance": "Black", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}], [{"position": [1, 0], "next_white": [2, 0], "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [1, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [1, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": [2, 2], "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}], [{"position": [2, 0], "next_white": [3, 0], "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [2, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [2, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": [3, 2], "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}], [{"position": [3, 0], "next_white": [4, 0], "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [3, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [3, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": [4, 2], "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}], [{"position": [4, 0], "next_white": [5, 0], "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [4, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [4, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": [5, 2], "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}], [{"position": [5, 0], "next_white": [6, 0], "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [5, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [5, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": [6, 2], "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}], [{"position": [6, 0], "next_white": [7, 0], "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [6, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [6, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": [7, 2], "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}], [{"position": [7, 0], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}, {"position": [7, 1], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": true}, {"position": [7, 2], "next_white": null, "next_black": null, "exit": "", "entrance": "", "rosette": false, "forbidden": false}]]
```

**what I tried:**

```
def play_game(self):

    piece = UrPiece(WHITE, 'W')
    bs_1 = BoardSquare(1, 1)
    bs_1.piece = piece
    piece.position = bs_1
    if bs_1.piece:
        self.display_board()
```

gives the same output.

```
def play_game(self):
    """
        Your job is to recode this function to play the game.
    """
    piece = UrPiece(WHITE, 'W')
    bs_1 = BoardSquare(1, 0)
  #  bs_1.piece = piece
    self.board[1][0] = bs_1
    self.display_board()
```

gives the same output. but

```
def play_game(self):

    piece = UrPiece(WHITE, 'W')
    bs_1 = BoardSquare(1, 0)
    bs_1.piece = piece
    self.board[1][0] = bs_1
    self.display_board()
```

gives an error:

```
    output[MAX_Y * i + y][MAX_X * j + x] = '+'
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

How can I update the board object so that piece atribute in BoardSquare is UrPiece.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful. What happened and how did it differ from what you expected? If you got an exception, post the full traceback.

Comment: sorry , "doesn't work" means it doesn't display piece like in expected output. There's no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed the code.

**test.py**

```
class UrPiece:
    WhiteStarts = []
    BlackStarts = []
    WhiteEnds = []
    BlackEnds = []
    def __init__(self, color, symbol):
        self.color = color
        self.position = None
        self.complete = False
        self.symbol = symbol

    def can_move(self, num_moves):
        if (self.complete == True and self.position and num_moves > 1):
            return False
        elif (self.complete == True and self.position == None):
            return False
        else:
            return True



class BoardSquare:
    def __init__(self, x, y, entrance=False, _exit=False, rosette=False, forbidden=False):
        self.piece = None
        self.position = (x, y)
        self.next_white = None
        self.next_black = None
        self.exit = _exit
        self.entrance = entrance
        self.rosette = rosette
        self.forbidden = forbidden

    def load_from_json(self, json_string):
        import json
        loaded_position = json.loads(json_string)
        self.piece = None
        self.position = loaded_position['position']
        self.next_white = loaded_position['next_white']
        self.next_black = loaded_position['next_black']
        self.exit = loaded_position['exit']
        self.entrance = loaded_position['entrance']
        self.rosette = loaded_position['rosette']
        self.forbidden = loaded_position['forbidden']

    def jsonify(self):
        next_white = self.next_white.position if self.next_white else None
        next_black = self.next_black.position if self.next_black else None
        return {'position': self.position, 'next_white': next_white, 'next_black': next_black, 'exit': self.exit, 'entrance': self.entrance, 'rosette': self.rosette, 'forbidden': self.forbidden}
```

**test2.py**

```
from sys import argv
from random import choice, randint
from test import BoardSquare, UrPiece

WHITE = 'White'
BLACK = 'Black'


# players = dict()

class RoyalGameOfUr:
    STARTING_PIECES = 7

    def __init__(self, board_file_name):
        self.players = {}
        self.board = None
        self.load_board(board_file_name)
        self.num_pieces = 0

    def load_board(self, board_file_name):
        """
        This function takes a file name and loads the map, creating BoardSquare objects in a grid.

        :param board_file_name: the board file name
        :return: sets the self.board object within the class
        """

        import json
        try:
            with open(board_file_name) as board_file:
                board_json = json.loads(board_file.read())
                self.num_pieces = self.STARTING_PIECES
                self.board = []
                for x, row in enumerate(board_json):
                    self.board.append([])
                    for y, square in enumerate(row):
                        self.board[x].append(BoardSquare(x, y, entrance=square['entrance'], _exit=square['exit'],
                                                         rosette=square['rosette'], forbidden=square['forbidden']))

                for i in range(len(self.board)):
                    for j in range(len(self.board[i])):
                        if board_json[i][j]['next_white']:
                            x, y = board_json[i][j]['next_white']
                            self.board[i][j].next_white = self.board[x][y]
                        if board_json[i][j]['next_black']:
                            x, y = board_json[i][j]['next_black']
                            self.board[i][j].next_black = self.board[x][y]
        except OSError:
            print('The file was unable to be opened. ')

    def draw_block(self, output, i, j, square):
        """
        Helper function for the display_board method
        :param output: the 2d output list of strings
        :param i: grid position row = i
        :param j: grid position col = j
        :param square: square information, should be a BoardSquare object
        """
        MAX_X = 8
        MAX_Y = 5
        for y in range(MAX_Y):
            for x in range(MAX_X):
                if x == 0 or y == 0 or x == MAX_X - 1 or y == MAX_Y - 1:
                    output[MAX_Y * i + y][MAX_X * j + x] = '+'
                if square.rosette and (y, x) in [(1, 1), (1, MAX_X - 2), (MAX_Y - 2, 1), (MAX_Y - 2, MAX_X - 2)]:
                    output[MAX_Y * i + y][MAX_X * j + x] = '*'
                if square.piece:
                    # print(square.piece.symbol)
                    output[MAX_Y * i + 2][MAX_X * j + 3: MAX_X * j + 5] = square.piece.symbol

    def display_board(self):
        """
        Draws the board contained in the self.board object

        """
        if self.board:
            output = [[' ' for _ in range(8 * len(self.board[i // 5]))] for i in range(5 * len(self.board))]
            for i in range(len(self.board)):
                for j in range(len(self.board[i])):
                    if not self.board[i][j].forbidden:
                        self.draw_block(output, i, j, self.board[i][j])

            print('\n'.join(''.join(output[i]) for i in range(5 * len(self.board))))

    def moves_get(self, player, num_moves):
        moves_allowed = []
        for piece in player:
            if piece.can_move(num_moves):
                moves_allowed.append(piece)

        return moves_allowed

    def cont_play(self, players):
        for player in players:
            if all((piece.complete for piece in players[player])):
                return False

        return True

    def start_moovement(self, the_piece, dice_results):
        if the_piece.position:
            x, y = the_piece.position.position
            self.board[x][y].piece.position = None
            self.board[x][y].piece = None
            position = self.board[x][y]
        else:
            dice_results -= 1
            if the_piece.color == 'White':
                position = UrPiece.WhiteStarts[0]
            else:
                position = UrPiece.BlackStarts[0]
        for i in range(dice_results):
            if the_piece.color == 'White':
                position = position.next_white

        if position:
            x, y = position.position
            the_piece.position = self.board[x][y]
            if self.board[x][y].piece:
                print(self.board[x][y].piece.symbol, 'has been knocked off')
                self.board[x][y].piece.position = None
                self.board[x][y].piece = None
            self.board[x][y].piece = the_piece
        else:
            the_piece.position = None
            the_piece.complete = True
            print(the_piece.symbol, 'has completed its path.')
        return position

    def player_init(self):
        player_name = input('What is your name? ')
        self.players[player_name] = [UrPiece('White', 'W{}'.format(i + 1)) for i in range(self.STARTING_PIECES)]
        print('{} you will play as white.'.format(player_name))
        player_name = input('What is your name? ')
        self.players[player_name] = [UrPiece('Black', 'B{}'.format(i + 1)) for i in range(self.STARTING_PIECES)]
        print('{} you will play as black.'.format(player_name))

    def play_game(self):
        if not self.board:
            print('Unable to start the game until the board is loaded')
            return
        turn = 0
        self.player_init()
        player_names = list(self.players.keys())
        player = self.players[player_names[turn]]
        for i in range(len(self.board)):
            for j in range(len(self.board[i])):
                if self.board[i][j].entrance == 'White':
                    UrPiece.WhiteStarts.append(self.board[i][j])
                else:
                    if self.board[i][j].entrance == 'Black':
                        UrPiece.BlackStarts.append(self.board[i][j])

        while self.cont_play(self.players):
            self.display_board()
            player = self.players[player_names[turn]]
            dice_results = self.roll_d4_dice()
            print('You rolled', dice_results)
            while self.take_turn(player, dice_results):
                self.display_board()
                print('You have landed on a rosette, go again. ')
                dice_results = self.roll_d4_dice()

            turn = (turn + 1) % 2

        print(player_names[((turn + 1) % 2)], 'has won the game.')

    def take_turn(self, player, dice_results):
        moves_allowed = self.moves_get(player, dice_results)
        for i, move in enumerate(moves_allowed):
            if not move.position:
                print(i + 1, move.symbol, 'currently off the board')
            else:
                print(i + 1, move.symbol, move.position.position)

        for piece in player:
            if piece.complete:
                print(piece.symbol, 'has completed the race.')

        if moves_allowed and dice_results:
            move = int(input('Which move do you wish to make? '))
            while move not in range(1, len(moves_allowed) + 1):
                move = int(input("Sorry, that wasn't a valid selection, which move do you wish to make? "))

            final_position = self.start_moovement(moves_allowed[(move - 1)], dice_results)
            if final_position and final_position.rosette:
                return True
        else:
            print('No moves are possible with the current dice roll. ')
        return False

    def roll_d4_dice(self, n=4):
        """
        :param n: the number of tetrahedral d4 to roll, each with one dot on
        :return: the result of the four rolls.
        """
        dots = 0
        for _ in range(n):
            dots += choice([0, 1])

        return dots


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = input('What is the file name of the board json? ') if len(argv) < 2 else argv[1]
    #file_name = 'original_board.ur'
    rgu = RoyalGameOfUr(file_name)
    rgu.play_game()
```